# can we only use specific part from SCSS partial file?

Tags: css, sass, partial

I only want to import specific part from SCSS file.
I need this approach so that we can speed up the application.
I'm using @use and @forward, what is happening in my case is when i'm importing any partial file it's refereeing whole CSS file due to this having converge 98.4% instead of referring whole variable file want those specific part to be import only.